# Installing MSI in Jenkins through pushtool or plugins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I want to install MSI on my remote machine.Earlier I was using final builder which has an option to use pushtool to install MSI(pacakage) on servers.Now I have moved to jenkins and I am looking for any plugins which can be used to install the MSI .Another approach is calling pushtool.exe by powershell scripts.

Start-Process -FilePath "D:\PushInstall\PushInstall.exe" -ArgumentList  "D:\PushInstall\installation.thom.DEV1.xml" -Wait

Even I gave -I option whhich stands for installation. But still it's not working.Can anyone help to solve this issue?